# Keep binary files on control version system

Tags: svn, version-control, release

We are working on a project and also in contact with out QC team to test our rapid developments and updates. So, sometimes we have several commits on our VCS (SVN in this case) to update or fix bugs.
After development, QC team should check and test, sometimes just after a commit or update. By the way, QC team members do not have any access to source code to build and make binary files (needed for testing) due to some security policies. Binary files are generated during build and development easily.
So, our developers should build and make binaries (RPM files in this case) and put them for test member team.
**Center Question:**

*Is that convenient and technically right* to put binaries (RPM files) on the VCS (and give an access to that directory ( or path including just binary files) to QC team members)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be placing your compiled binaries/packages in your source repository. Any artifact that can be created from the contents of the repository should not be placed back into the repository.

Instead, your continuous integration/deployment system (**not your developers**) should be checking out, compiling the code, running tests, packaging things up and then publishing to another internal repository of binaries/compiled artifacts. Note that this is **not** necessarily a VCS - in fact, it probably shouldn't be. More likely it'll be a repository that's accessible to the package managers that your QC team will then retrieve and test - like your build & deploy process, preferably via automation.

Comment: in regards to your first paragraph, can you give some reasons _why_ artifacts should not be checked in?

Comment: It's redundant, a waste of space, and adds unnecessary clutter to the repository. If you have everything else required to create those items in the repository, you can re-create them at any time in the future.